# Getting Class Cast Exception when I unit test a repository

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, spring-test

I'm migrating an application from Java8 to Java11 and using the following dependencies
Java 11
Spring: 5.1.0
powermock-module-junit4 : 2.0.2
powermock-api-mockito2: 2.0.2
mockito-core: 2.27.0
JUnit: 4.12

I've repositories and I had to test the functionality of it. And in my unit test case, I'm using powermock to mock the objects. Let's say I've this method to be tested in **SomeRepoImpl.java**

```
public Page<Locale> someMethod(List<String> queryFields, Map<String, Object> filters, Pageable p) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Locale> criteria = builder.createQuery(Locale.class);
    Root<Locale> root = criteria.from(Locale.class);
    Selection<?>[] s = new Selection<?>[queryFields.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (String field : queryFields) {
        s[i++] = CriteriaUtils.getField(root, field);
    }
    criteria.select(builder.construct(Locale.class, s));

    Sort sort = p.getSort();
    if (null != sort) {
        List<Order> list = new ArrayList<Order>(3);
        Iterator<Sort.Order> item = sort.iterator();
        Sort.Order o = null;
        while (item.hasNext()) {
            o = item.next();
            if (o.isAscending()) {
                list.add(builder.asc(root.get(o.getProperty())));
            } else {
                list.add(builder.desc(root.get(o.getProperty())));
            }
        }
        criteria.orderBy(list);
    }

    Predicate[] predicates = null;
    if (null != filters && filters.size() > 0) {
        predicates = new Predicate[filters.size()];
        i = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : filters.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Object val = entry.getValue();
            predicates[i++] = builder.equal(CriteriaUtils.getField(root, key), val);
        }
        if (null != predicates) {
            criteria.where(predicates);
        }
    }
    System.err.println("The value of P: "+p);
    List<Locale> content = em.createQuery(criteria).setFirstResult(p.getOffset()).setMaxResults(p.getPageSize())
            .getResultList();
    Long count = (Long)getCountQuery(predicates).getSingleResult();
    return new PageImpl<Locale>(content, p, count);
}
```

And for the above repository function, I've the below test code I've written(Correct me if I'm wrong), I'm new to this.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.management.*", "sun.*", "javax.net.ssl.*" })
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:/spring/test-context.xml" })
public class SomeRepositoryTest {

@Mock
EntityManager em;
@Mock
Query query;
@Mock
CriteriaQuery<Locale> criteriaQuery;
@Mock
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder;
@Mock
Root<Locale> root;
@Mock
Predicate predicate;
@Mock
Selection<Locale> selection;
@Mock
Path<Object> path;
@Mock
CompoundSelection<Locale> compondSelection;
@Mock
TypedQuery<Locale> typedQuery;
@Mock
CriteriaQuery<Long> criteriaQueryLong;
@Mock
TypedQuery<Long> typedQueryLong;
@Mock
Root<Locale> policyRootLong;
@InjectMocks
SomeRepoImpl someRepoImpl;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    
    List<Locale> listOfLocale = new ArrayList<>();
    Locale locale = new Locale("testCode");
    listOfLocale.add(locale);
    
    Selection<?>[] s = new Selection<?>[1];
    PowerMockito.when(em.getCriteriaBuilder()).thenReturn(criteriaBuilder);
    PowerMockito.when(criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Locale.class)).thenReturn(criteriaQuery);
    PowerMockito.when(criteriaQuery.from(Locale.class)).thenReturn(root);
    PowerMockito.when(criteriaQuery.select(root)).thenReturn(criteriaQuery);
    PowerMockito.when(root.get("langCode")).thenReturn(path);
    s[0] = path;
    PowerMockito.when(criteriaBuilder.construct(Locale.class, s)).thenReturn(compondSelection);
    PowerMockito.when(criteriaQuery.select(compondSelection)).thenReturn(criteriaQuery);
    PowerMockito.when(em.createQuery(criteriaQuery)).thenReturn(typedQuery);
    PowerMockito.when(typedQuery.setFirstResult(0)).thenReturn(typedQuery);
    PowerMockito.when(typedQuery.setMaxResults(4)).thenReturn(typedQuery);
    PowerMockito.when(typedQuery.getResultList()).thenReturn(listOfLocale);
    
    //For Long
    PowerMockito.when(criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class)).thenReturn(criteriaQueryLong);
    PowerMockito.when(criteriaQueryLong.from(Locale.class)).thenReturn(policyRootLong);
    PowerMockito.when(criteriaQueryLong.select(criteriaBuilder.count(policyRootLong))).thenReturn(criteriaQueryLong);
    PowerMockito.when(em.createQuery(criteriaQueryLong)).thenReturn(typedQueryLong);
    PowerMockito.when(typedQueryLong.getSingleResult()).thenReturn(2L);
    
}

@Test
public void performTest() {
    List<String> queryFields = new ArrayList<String>();
    queryFields.add("one");
    queryFields.add("two");
    queryFields.add("three");
    queryFields.add("four");
    
    Map<String, Object> filters = null;
    Pageable page = new PageRequest(0, 4);
    
    PowerMockito.when(localerepo.loadLocaleListByCondition(queryFields, filters, page)).thenReturn(new PageImpl<Locale>(new ArrayList<Locale>() {{
        add(new Locale("testCode"));
    }}, page, 2));
    
    Page<Locale> result = someRepoImpl.loadLocaleListByCondition(queryFields,filters,page);
    Assert.assertNotNull(result);
    Assert.assertTrue(result.getContent() != null);
    Assert.assertTrue(result.getTotalElements() > 0);
}
```

}

And I'm getting the following exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long (org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl is in unnamed module of loader org.powermock.core.classloader.javassist.JavassistMockClassLoader @6483f5ae; java.lang.Long is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at com.somepackage.SomeRepoImpl.someMethod(SomeRepoImpl.java:90)
at com.somepackage.SomeRepositoryTest.performTest(SomeRepositoryTest.java:140)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

I've been trying to understand this but unable to. Any help would be much appriciated.

Comment: the problem is not in your test, it's in your implementation. The first line of the stacktrace tells you what the problem is, the second line tells you at which line it occurs.

Comment: @Stultuske Thanks. But it didn't help

Comment: "But it didn't help" ... just reading the comment won't help indeed. What have you tried to do that didn't help?

Comment: Unrelated, but I guess still important: Your test has fourteen (14!) mocks and you're literally duplicating your implementation inside your test. This test brings little benefit to your project. When testing database related parts of your application, try to  involve the database instead of mocking everything. If you have the chance to add Spring Boot, [@DataJpaTest](https://rieckpil.de/test-your-spring-boot-jpa-persistence-layer-with-datajpatest/) might help you a lot here.

Comment: For further help, please indicate line 90 of your implementation and line 140 of your test as this is where the error occurs (according to the stacktrace)